# Getting unnecessary bullet for li of an ul only in firefox and ie

Tags: html, css

I have an ul and some li's fall under it, everything is fine, but the issue is first li is getting an extra bullet in firefox and ie in rest of the browsers its fine

html

```
<div id="listItems">
    <div class="colorBlock orange"></div>
    <span>4 pts (1)</span>
     <ul id="dlrsList">
          <li >Crosstown Auto Centre</li>
          <li >Grande Prairie Chrysler Jeep Dodge</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
#dlrsList {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: justify;
            display: list-item;            
            li {             
                padding: 0px;
                position: relative;                
                bottom: 8px;                                
                max-width: 160px;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try setting the line-style in the CSS as none. For example: li {list-style: none;}. In any case post the HTML and CSS and tell us the browser and version.

Comment: Your CSS looks more like LESS, with the nested selector. Is that what you're using?

Comment: i want the bullets, issue is i am two bullets for first li

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is working fine just checked it here http://jsfiddle.net/TGVKu/

same css

```
#dlrsList {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: justify;
            display: list-item;            
            li {             
                padding: 0px;
                position: relative;                
                bottom: 8px;                                
                max-width: 160px;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
        }
```

Apologies I should have added this in a comment but I dont have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: that's fine it worked in the fiddle but i am getting an extra dot for the first li so totally i am two dots for first li

Comment: I dont know what exactly is your problem but from my side only thing i can suggest is add this javascript to your page to remove the li style $(document).ready(function() {
   $('ul li:first-child').css('list-style-type','none');
 });

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the CSS and doing something like this:

```
#dlrsList ul {
   width: 100%;
   text-align: justify;
   display: list-item;                       
}

#dlrsList ul li {             
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;                
    bottom:8px;                                
    max-width: 160px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I suggest that the format you are using, although it is valid, is confusing the browser.

Comment: r u sure that gonna work if i give styles in detail with out confusing

Comment: I tried it in fiddle and it worked just fine. Obversely you must try it in context to be sure.